# Http Routing Mesh on Windows

Tags: docker-swarm, docker-for-windows, docker-ucp

I tried to implement HRM using this article.

[Docker HRM Windows](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.1/guides/admin/configure/use-domain-names-to-access-services/)

However, I get no response when I hit wordpress.example.com

But I do get response when I replace the domain with manager node’s ip like http://10.54.52.79:8000

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Name resolution is for interswarm communication not for external hosts, those will still use your nominal DNS servers

Comment: what does that mean? I followed the steps exactly as mentioned in the article. Is there anything i should do differently?

Comment: You will get name resolution working inside containers themselves but not fo your host. Login into running container and try to resovle name `wordpress.example.com` it shall resolve to IP of 10.54.52.79